# Loop through folders for Excel files that end in List.xlsx

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open 1300 Excel files in separate subfolders and change the same cell on the same tab of each file.

I'm having problems with `Workbook.open` and making sure its selecting the correct Excel files.

The files are in subfolders of a parent folder.
The files all end in List.xlsx

```vb
Sub LoopFilesInFolder()
Dim folderName As String
Dim FSOLibrary As FileSystemObject
Dim FSOFolder As Object
Dim FSOFile As Object

'Set the file name to a variable
folderName = "\\net\fs1\users\alex.wood\Desktop\TC Excel Test and Creation Files\VBA TEST FOLDER"

'Set all the references to the FSO Library
Set FSOLibrary = New FileSystemObject
Set FSOFolder = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(folderName)
Set FSOFile = FSOFolder.Files

'Use For Each loop to loop through each file in the folder
For Each FSOFile In FSOFile
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Dir("\\net\fs1\users\alex.wood\Desktop\TC Excel Test and Creation Files\VBA TEST FOLDER\*list*")

    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "New Thin Client"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close

Next

'Release the memory
Set FSOLibrary = Nothing
Set FSOFolder = Nothing
Set FSOFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba

Answer (score 1):

You can do that

```
Sub LoopFilesInFolder()
    'Improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    mypath = "\\net\fs1\users\alex.wood\Desktop\TC Excel Test and Creation Files\VBA TEST FOLDER\"

    myfile = Dir(mypath & "*.xls*")
  
    Do While myfile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open mypath & myfile
        Workbooks(myfile).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Value = "New Thin Client"
        Workbooks(myfile).Save
        Workbooks(myfile).Close
        myfile = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: It does not error out it does not do anything. It acts like the macro is completed but it did not update anything

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a \ in the end of `mypath`. You can include a `MsgBox myfile` right before `myfile = Dir` to get the name of file edited.