# Looping through and opening a directory of files with Excel VBA Dir() function quitting early

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop through a directory of .csv files, retrieve a piece of information from each one and compile in a new .xlsx file.

The Dir() function is bailing well before looping through 500 files.

---

My solution based on this thread: [VBA code to loop through files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63357500/vba-code-to-loop-through-files-in-a-folder).

Apparently, while this function was executing, another thing (I assume a Word document I was writing) was telling the macro to stop with no error code. It was exiting out of a while -> wend loop leaving the last document the function visited opened and not executing the close statement. I confirmed this running the macro without anything else open.

If the Dir() function stops execution before checking every file in a directory, close other MicroSoft applications.

---

What exactly is going on? Is there a way to further mitigate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the `Dir` bug, collect the files first and then process them. Do not do any office related stuff between the calls to `Dir`.

```vb
Option Explicit

' Get the files specified
Function GetFiles(MyFolder As String) As Variant
    Dim MyFile As Variant, Files As Variant
    Dim NumFiles As Long, Idx As Long
    
    ' Collect files only and ignore folders
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder)
    NumFiles = 0
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        NumFiles = NumFiles + 1
        If NumFiles = 1 Then
            ReDim Files(1 To 1)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve Files(1 To NumFiles)
        End If
        Files(NumFiles) = MyFile
        MyFile = Dir()
    Loop
    GetFiles = Files
End Function

Sub ProcessFiles(MyFolder As String)
    Dim MyFile As Variant
    Dim Files As Variant
    Dim Idx As Long
    
    Files = GetFiles(MyFolder)
    If Not IsEmpty(Files) Then
        For Idx = LBound(Files) To UBound(Files)
            MyFile = Files(Idx)
            ' Process the file here
            Debug.Print MyFile
        Next Idx
    Else
        Debug.Print "No files found for Dir(""" & MyFolder & """)"
    End If
End Sub

Sub TestProcessFiles()
    ProcessFiles "C:\windows\*.*"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a known bug?

Comment: @Dan I don't know if it's a *known bug*. When I found the fix, I didn't bother to try to track the error down, but I suspect that working with multiple office documents,  can somehow reset the global environment. Also if you do not handle errors and make sure to clear them, you can get undefined behavior.